Certificates informations
When accessing the Windows certificate store, you can view a property called 'Description' in the "Details" tab. I am unable to retrieve this using a PowerShell or .NET command. Does anyone have this information, dear community?
$certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\
$certs[2] | select *

PSPath                   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My\000000000000000
PSParentPath             : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My
PSChildName              : 000000000000000
PSDrive                  : Cert
PSProvider               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate
PSIsContainer            : False
EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Authentication du serveur (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)}
DnsNameList              : {SERVER.DOMAIN.FR}
SendAsTrustedIssuer      : False
EnrollmentPolicyEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
EnrollmentServerEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
PolicyId                 : {0000}
Archived                 : False
Extensions               : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}
FriendlyName             : FRIENDLY_NAME
IssuerName               : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
NotAfter                 : 09/01/2027 16:38:30
NotBefore                : 10/01/2024 16:38:30
HasPrivateKey            : True
PrivateKey               : System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
PublicKey                : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey
RawData                  : {48, 130, 6, 211...}
SerialNumber             : 000000000000000
SubjectName              : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
SignatureAlgorithm       : System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Thumbprint               : 000000000000000
Version                  : 3
Handle                   : 000000000000000
Issuer                   : CN=DOMAIN.FR, DC=DOMAIN, DC=FR
Subject                  : CN=SERVER.DOMAIN.FR, OU=DOMAIN, L=CITY, S=STATE, C=UK


You are looking at a registry item.  Can you see description using Regedit?

@jdweng Cert: is the default drive of the Certificate provider, nothing to do with registry items.

Description is not part of the certificate itself and is vendor specific. For windows, you can use this code to pull the description
$signature = @"
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool CertGetCertificateContextProperty(
    IntPtr pCertContext,
    uint dwPropId,
    Byte[] pvData,
    ref uint pcbData
);
"@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Namespace PKI -Name Crypt32
$pcbData = 0
# if the function returns False, then description is not specified.
$CERT_DESCRIPTION_PROP_ID = 13

$certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | Select-Object *,@{n='Description';e={
    if ([PKI.Crypt32]::CertGetCertificateContextProperty($_.Handle,$CERT_DESCRIPTION_PROP_ID,$null,[ref]$pcbData)) {
        # allocate a buffer to store property value
        $pvData = New-Object byte[] -ArgumentList $pcbData
        # call the function again to write actual data into allocated buffer
        [void][PKI.Crypt32]::CertGetCertificateContextProperty($_.Handle,$CERT_DESCRIPTION_PROP_ID,$pvData,[ref]$pcbData)
        # Description is null-terminated unicode string
        [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($pvData).TrimEnd()
    }
}}

Reference the accepted answer here
EDIT
I actually like this approach better, using a scriptproperty
$certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Description -Value {
    $signature = @"
    [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CertGetCertificateContextProperty(
        IntPtr pCertContext,
        uint dwPropId,
        Byte[] pvData,
        ref uint pcbData
    );
"@

    if($null -eq ('PKI.Crypt32' -as [type])){
        Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Namespace PKI -Name Crypt32
    }

    $pcbData = 0
    # if the function returns False, then description is not specified.
    $CERT_DESCRIPTION_PROP_ID = 13

    if ([PKI.Crypt32]::CertGetCertificateContextProperty($this.Handle,$CERT_DESCRIPTION_PROP_ID,$null,[ref]$pcbData)) {
        # allocate a buffer to store property value
        $pvData = New-Object byte[] -ArgumentList $pcbData
        # call the function again to write actual data into allocated buffer
        [void][PKI.Crypt32]::CertGetCertificateContextProperty($this.Handle,$CERT_DESCRIPTION_PROP_ID,$pvData,[ref]$pcbData)
        # Description is null-terminated unicode string
        [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($pvData).TrimEnd()
    }
} -PassThru

